# Find ListView Items based on text of items and sub items

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have `listview` with 2 groups (`ONLINE` and `OFFLINE`) and two columns (`Name` and `Status`).

[ListView Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQCJH.png)

This is my code to add items into specific group:

```
public void f2list(object group, string friend, string status)
{
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { friend, (string)status });
        GroupItem(item, group);
        this.ListView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

`object group` defines in which group item will be added `OFFLINE` or `ONLINE` , 
`string friend` defines friends username and `string status` is just second column `Status`

Second part of that code:

```
private void GroupItem(ListViewItem item, object group2)
{
        foreach (ListViewGroup group in this.ListView.Groups)
        {
            if (group.Header == (string)group2)
            {
                item.Group = group;
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

So, I need somehow move items between those two groups or remove item `name` and `status` from list so it can be added in another group again.

I know how to remove `selected` item when I click on it, but how to do that when other class or function call 'move that specific item/assign that specific item to another group'?

This `f2list` is called by another `public void AddUserToList`, but this is only to assign text like `f2list(group,username,status);` (eg. `f2list("ONLINE","Joe","Hey i am online!");` and also its check if `username` already exist to prevent double items.

How to move item between groups depends which groups is called in `f2list(group, ...`?  This `group` is predefined `OFFLINE` or `ONLINE`

So when `Name` aka `username` comes online to show in `listview` and group `ONLINE` but when he/she goes offline then assign to another group `OFFLINE`?

**Additional info:** This code works fine only to add items to the list. But how to move items between those two groups? Or even remove item from list where group is `OFFLINE` or `ONLINE`?

**EDIT** Also when I manually remove `selected` item this item will change group correctly.

**EDIT 2** Those items are added by `timer` which checks others users if they are online or offline.

Comment: Do you want to change group of selected Item?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Not `selected` item with eg. mouse click, i want to change group of item found by for example FindByText method or something similar.

Comment: Just find the item by a method or by user click, then set `Group` property of the item to suitable value. What's the problem?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Problem is i'm not familiar with multicolumn listview (i never used that) so i'm not sure how to find item by `Name` of how to search/filter for `Name` in only `ONLINE` or `OFFLINE` groups, not in entire listview, just in groups. :/   EDIT: I can use this code `GoupItem` to change group of item but it will not show changed item, it will stay as was beffore when it's first time added into list.

Comment: I shared some useful methods for you. To find an item, find a group and move an item to a group.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you, i will try it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Find an Item using FindItemWithText**

To find an `Item` based on `Text` of item you can use [`FindItemWithText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var item = this.listView1.FindItemWithText("item text");
```

You can also use other signatures to include sub-items in search:

```
var item = this.listView1.FindItemWithText("", true, 0);
```

**Find an Item using Linq**

Also to perform a custom search, you can use `Linq` methods. For example:

```
var item = this.listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                .Where(x => (x.Text == "Some Text" ||
                       x.SubItems[1].Text == "Some Text") &&
                       x.Group.Name=="group1" )
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Find a Group**

When creating groups, assign suitable names to groups and then find them by name. Pay attention `Name` is different from `HeaderText`. To find a group by name, you can:

```
var group = this.listView1.Groups["group1"];
```

**Move an Item to a Group**

To move an `Item` to a `Group`, it's enough to find the item and find the group you want, then simply assign the group to `Group` property of `Item`:

```
item.Group = group;
```

Comment: This is actually really simple. Thank you very much.